# have two date formats in a single line in a flat file "MMddyyyy" and "MMddyyyyHHmm"

Tags: spring-batch

how can i use org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor if i have 2 date formats in a single line in a flat file.

```
<bean id="dateEditor1"  class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
<constructor-arg value="MMddyyyy" />
  </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
 <constructor-arg value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="dateEditor2" class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">

<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
        <constructor-arg value="MMddyyyyHHmm" />
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="true" />

</bean>

<property name="customEditors">
      <map>
        <entry key="java.util.Date" value-ref="dateEditor1"/>
        <entry key="java.util.Date" value-ref="dateEditor1"/>
      </map>
</property>
```

I am trying the above code. but it doesnt work. i am useing PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.

Comment: I didn't get you, if you have 2 different formats , reference to difference formats in the bean.. what is that map ?

Answer (score 1):

Used the below custom date format:

```
public class CustomDateFormats extends DateFormat {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String[] formats = new String[] { "MMddyyyy", "MMddyyyyHHmm", "MMdd" };
Date result = null;

@Override
public StringBuffer format(final Date date, final StringBuffer toAppendTo, final FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This custom date formatter can only be used to *parse* Dates.");
}

@Override
public Date parse(final String source, final ParsePosition pos) {
    Date res = null;

    for (String format : formats) {
        if (source != null && format.length() == source.length()) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            res = sdFormat.parse(source, pos);
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
 }

 }
 <bean id="dateEditor1"       class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
    <constructor-arg>
<bean class="com.disney.wdpro.service.transaction.processing.batch.domain.logicalBatchOpen.CustomDateFormats" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Look at the map where you are trying using java.util.Date as key and then you are expecting it to hold 2 values. map doesn't work that way, it will always override the value if the key is already existing. Thus in your case you have to write a customized bean for to set these fields in your flat file.

According to the Spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor)),only one single registered custom editor per property path is supported.

But you can write a custom dateformat class which will hold a list of different date formats and use this class to autowire to custom editor.
For example one like given below or you create your customized editor and wrap a list of CustomDateEditor , There are multiple use , you can refer to one example like below.

```
<bean id="customer4" class="org.testSpring.util.DateBeanTest4">
    <property name="birthDate">
        <bean factory-bean="customDateFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="31-01-2010" />
            <!-- mm/dd/yyyy, dd-MM-yyyy, yyyyMMdd -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
   <bean id="customDateFormat" class="org.testSpring.util.CustomDateFormats">
</bean>
```

And your formatter class

```
public class CustomDateFormats extends DateFormat {

private static final List<? extends DateFormat> DATE_FORMATS = Arrays.asList(
    // or inject thorough construction with a list of formats
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")); 


@Override
public StringBuffer format(final Date date, final StringBuffer toAppendTo, final FieldPosition fieldPosition) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This custom date formatter can only be used to *parse* Dates.");
}

@Override
public Date parse(final String source, final ParsePosition pos) {
    Date res = null;
    for (final DateFormat dateFormat : DATE_FORMATS) {
        if ((res = dateFormat.parse(source, pos)) != null) {
            return res;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: i need it for my item reader in my spring batch processor.

can i do the below :




`code`
 



     <bean id="LBOFieldSetMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
  <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="BatchOpenTransactionData" />
  
  <!-- <property name="customEditors">
    <map>
     <entry key="java.util.Date" value-ref="customDateFormat"/>
   <
    </map>
  </property>   -->
 </bean>
     </bean>
   <bean id="customDateFormat" class="org.testSpring.util.CustomDateFormats">
     </bean>
`code`